# How can I disable WPS on DD-WRT?

Tags: dd-wrt

I have a Buffalo AirStation router with **DD-WRT** installed.

My version is `Firmware: DD-WRT v24SP2-EU-US (08/19/10) std` (latest as for today on my device), but I think this question is basically the same for any DD-WRT:

What is the method to **disable WPS** in Wireless configuration?
I can not find where it is.

Additional Info:

- Some people reports this setting is at `Wireless --> AOSS --> Disable`, but this doesn't work for me (WPS keeps active, or so reports any Android device on the nearby).

Comment: Are you 100% you are running the current firmware?  Please provide more information than "it doesn't work" that tells us virtually nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extracted from [this thread](http://www.dd-wrt.com/phpBB2/viewtopic.php?t=149251) at DD-WRT forums:

> Short answer: your WPS could already be disabled on your DD-WRT
>   device, even when it seems to be active. It just depends on the
>   `wps_state` value at `/tmp/path[0-9]_hostap.conf` file: `1` means
>   active, `0` or `2` means it is not.

Time to test the real thing with [AirCrack-NG](http://www.aircrack-ng.org/).
If I **scan** with AiroDump-NG:

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ sudo airodump-ng wlan1mon --wps -c 2

 CH  2 ][ Elapsed: 1 min ][ 2015-12-15 00:48

 BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH WPS     ESSID

 XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX  -35 100      435       20    0   2  54e. WPA2 CCMP   PSK  Locked  MyWiFiNetWork
```

It seems there is some **WPS**, but in **Locked** state.

If I try to **attack** it via WPS with, say, [Bully](https://github.com/Lrs121/bully):

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ sudo bully wlan1mon --bssid 00:24:A5:XX:XX:XX -v 3 -c 2
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'wlan1mon' to channel '2'
[!] Using '00:1c:f0:9f:fc:84' for the source MAC address
[+] Datalink type set to '127', radiotap headers present
[+] Scanning for beacon from '00:24:a5:XX:XX:XX' on channel '2'
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Disabling FCS validation (assuming --nofcs)
[+] Got beacon for 'MyWiFiNetWork' (00:24:a5:XX:XX:XX)
[!] Beacon information element indicates WPS is locked
[+] Loading randomized pins from '/root/.bully/pins'
[!] Restoring session from '/root/.bully/0024a5c816a2.run'
[+] Index of starting pin number is '0000000'
[+] Last State = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '64121635'
[!] WPS lockout reported, sleeping for 43 seconds ...
^C
Saved session to '/root/.bully/0024a5c816a2.run'
```

Indeed, it is **locked**.
If I **force** the attack even for the locked state:

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ sudo bully wlan1mon --bssid 00:24:A5:XX:XX:XX -v 3 -L -c 2
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'wlan1mon' to channel '2'
[!] Using '00:1c:f0:9f:fc:84' for the source MAC address
[+] Datalink type set to '127', radiotap headers present
[+] Scanning for beacon from '00:24:a5:XX:XX:XX' on channel '2'
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Disabling FCS validation (assuming --nofcs)
[+] Got beacon for 'MyWiFiNetWork' (00:24:a5:XX:XX:XX)
[!] Beacon information element indicates WPS is locked
[+] Loading randomized pins from '/root/.bully/pins'
[!] Restoring session from '/root/.bully/0024a5c816a2.run'
[+] Index of starting pin number is '0000000'
[+] Last State = 'NoAssoc'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
[+] Rx(  M1  ) = 'EAPFail'   Next pin '64121635'
```

So, there is no WPS, or at least **no WPS** available to attack.

Tested with both Enable/Disable state at `Wireless --> AOSS` (somebody reported it could change the WPS state):

[image]

Anyway, if you want to stay fully calm with that `WPS Enabled` message that you can see on, say, Android, follow these steps:

1.- Find the `hostapd.conf` file for your wireless card at `/tmp`. Mine is:

```
root@DD-WRT:/tmp# ls /tmp/*hostap.conf -la
-rw-r--r--    1 root     root          580 Dec 15 00:48 /tmp/ath0_hostap.conf
```

2.- Check the `wps_state` value:

```
root@DD-WRT:/tmp# cat ath0_hostap.conf | grep "wps" -i
wps_state=2
```

Note:

- `0` means WPS Disabled.
- `1` means WPS Enabled.
- `2` means WPS Locked.

3.- **Change** it to `0`. You could edit the file. I prefer to use the `sed` command to directly exchange `2` by `0`:

```
/bin/sed s/wps_state\=2/wps_state\=0/g -i /tmp/ath0_hostap.conf
```

4.- Locate the `hostapd` process (with its parameters):

```
root@DD-WRT:/tmp# ps | grep "apd" -i
   60 root         0 SW<  [kswapd0]
 2093 root      1340 S    hostapd -B /tmp/ath0_hostap.conf
```

5.- **Kill and restart** it (with exactly the same parameters):

```
root@DD-WRT:/tmp# kill 2093
root@DD-WRT:/tmp# hostapd -B /tmp/ath0_hostap.conf
```

And that should be all.
This time AirCrack-NG:

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ sudo airodump-ng wlan1mon --wps -c 2

 CH  2 ][ Elapsed: 12 s ][ 2015-12-15 00:57

 BSSID              PWR RXQ  Beacons    #Data, #/s  CH  MB   ENC  CIPHER AUTH WPS     ESSID

 00:24:A5:XX:XX:XX  -35 100       50        3    0   2  54e. WPA2 CCMP   PSK          MyWiFiNetWork

 BSSID              STATION            PWR   Rate    Lost    Frames  Probe
```

As can be seen, it shows **no WPS enabled** on the column.
And, this time, Bully-WPS will not even try to attack it:

```
luis@Frambuesio:~$ sudo bully wlan1mon --bssid 00:24:A5:XX:XX:XX -v 3 -c 2
[sudo] password for luis:
[!] Bully v1.0-22 - WPS vulnerability assessment utility
[+] Switching interface 'wlan1mon' to channel '2'
[!] Using '00:1c:f0:9f:fc:84' for the source MAC address
[+] Datalink type set to '127', radiotap headers present
[+] Scanning for beacon from '00:24:a5:XX:XX:XX' on channel '2'
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Excessive (3) FCS failures while reading next packet
[!] Disabling FCS validation (assuming --nofcs)
[+] Got beacon for 'MyWiFiNetWork' (00:24:a5:XX:XX:XX)
[X] The AP doesn't appear to be WPS enabled (no WPS IE)
```

So, finally, we can say that WPS is **disabled on your DD-WRT** router.

Tested with Buffalo WHR-HP-GN. Expected to work on any model (please confirm).

**Further Details**:

- As long as the `/tmp` dir corresponds to RAM, **this change is temporal**, unles you [script it](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Startup_Scripts.) in any manner for each reboot.
- On the above referred thread at DD-WRT forum there is some `/bin/ps | /bin/grep '[h]ostapd' | /usr/bin/awk -F" " {'print $1'} | /usr/bin/xargs /bin/kill -HUP` command line that directly replaces step 5.